# How does Nvidia's Fermi GPU issue threadblocks to streaming multiprocessor

Tags: cuda, gpu, multiprocessor

Assume I have 8 threadblocks and my GPU has 8 SMs. Then how does GPU issue this threadblocks to the SMs?

I found some programs or articles suggest a breadth-first manner, that is , each SM runs a threadblock in this example.
However, according to a few documents, increasing occupancy may be a good idea if GPU kernels are latency-limited. It might be inferred that 8 threadblocks will run on 4 or less SMs if it can.

I wonder which one is the reality.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what the GPU is doing exactly. If you have a specific kernel you're interested in, you could try reading and storing the `%smid` register for each block.

An example of how to do this is given [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/468126/using-smid-compiling-a-ptx-/).

Comment: Ok.. So Nvidia doesn't release information about this. Maybe I will try   this experiment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You ask the wrong question: you shouldn't worry about how hardware allocates thread-blocks to SMs. That's GPU's responsibility. In fact, since their programming model makes no assumptions as for which blocks will run on which SMs, you get scalability across a pool of computing devices/future generations.

Instead, you should try to feed GPU with the optimal number of thread-blocks. That's non-trivial, since it's subject to many restrictions